# Sort strings by natural ordering

Tags: sorting

Is there an easy way to sort strings according to their natural ordering?
For example a list of file names

```
names = FileNames["~/Hex_*.dat"]
{"~/Hex_12.dat", "~/Hex_192.dat", "~/Hex_24.dat", "~/Hex_48.dat", "~/Hex_6.dat", "~/Hex_96.dat"}
```

I could use

```
SortBy[names, ToExpression[StringCases[#, RegularExpression[".*Hex_([0-9]+)\\.dat"] -> "$1"][[1]]] &]
{"~/Hex_6.dat", "~/Hex_12.dat", "~/Hex_24.dat", "~/Hex_48.dat", "~/Hex_96.dat", "~/Hex_192.dat"}
```

to get the file names into natural ordering, but this is neither elegant nor portable.
Any better suggestions?

**Edit:**
Many thanks for the answers.

But there is one problem left. Although all suggestions work with the above example, what can I do if there is more than one number in the path?
Files like:

> A_1_1.dat, A_1_2.dat, ..., A_1_20.dat,
>   A_2_1.dat, A_2_2.dat, ..., A_2_20.dat,
>   ...

Another problem I have encountered are rational numbers like:

> T_0.23_run_1.dat, T_0.23_run_2.dat, ..., T_0.23_run_20.dat,
>   T_0.24_run_1.dat, T_0.24_run_2.dat, ..., T_0.24_run_20.dat,
>   ...

Comment: Regarding your edit, my answer presciently addresses your first case.  Actually, it addresses the second case to some degree as well.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I was just editing while you answered, so I did not see your answer in time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I share Leonid's reservations about basing the sort on simple string length.  I would use a similar `Ordering` method, but I would parse things differently.  Consider this test set:

```
names = {"~/Hex_12.dat", "~/Hex_192.dat", "~/Oct_99.dat", 
         "~/Hex_014.dat", "~/Hex_24_17.dat", "~/Hex_24_5.dat", 
         "~/Hex_48.dat", "~/Hex_6.dat", "~/Hex_96.dat", "~/Hex_nonum.dat"};
```

I would like my sort to recognize `_24_17` as number 24 with a sub-number of 17.  I would also like it to recognize `014` as 14.  To that end I propose this method:

```
names[[Ordering @
  PadRight @ StringSplit[names, x : DigitCharacter .. :> FromDigits@x]
]]

(*
~/Hex_6.dat
~/Hex_12.dat
~/Hex_014.dat
~/Hex_24_5.dat
~/Hex_24_17.dat
~/Hex_48.dat
~/Hex_96.dat
~/Hex_192.dat
~/Hex_nonum.dat
~/Oct_99.dat
*)
```

---

Your edited question includes two additional examples.  The first I anticipated in my answer above.  The second, handling numbers with a decimal point, requires different parsing:

```
names2 = {"T_5_run_1.dat", "T_5_run_2.dat", "T_5_run_1.5.dat", 
          "T_0.23_run_1.dat", "T_0.23_run_2.dat", "T_0.23_run_20.dat", 
          "T_0.24_run_1.dat", "T_0.24_run_2.dat", "T_0.24_run_20.dat"};

names2[[Ordering @
  PadRight @ StringSplit[names2, x : NumberString :> ToExpression@x]
]]

(*
T_0.23_run_1.dat
T_0.23_run_2.dat
T_0.23_run_20.dat
T_0.24_run_1.dat
T_0.24_run_2.dat
T_0.24_run_20.dat
T_5_run_1.dat
T_5_run_1.5.dat
T_5_run_2.dat
*)
```

Comment: +1 Brilliant. PS: any reason for the latex outputs?

Comment: @Ajasja Thanks.  Sorry, I realize I undid your edit with mine.  No particular reason, other than wanting a format that made comparing lines easy and this was expedient.  I presume you do not like it?

Comment: Nope, I find it harder to read (on chrome win7). Is this tex font monospaced?  I would argue for `(* => *)` or `>` . [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1xEYX.png)

Comment: I agree with Ajasja on the latex issue. I think made this point to belisarius earlier too, and my issue was only the fact that on slightly choppy connections, mathjax does take time to load and it is worse still when using mobile devices. So I'd probably use it only where necessary. In this case, tabular format using monospaced text would've worked just as fine. If you don't mind, I can edit it but generally I try not to touch these as people sometimes are sensitive about their preferred way of formatting

Comment: @R.M yes, people (read: I) can be, but please go ahead in this case.

Comment: My main point was not the exact parsing scheme but the code structure which should make it easy to specify and change one, and make for a robust functionality. Perhaps I did not articulate it well enough.

Answer (score 22):

This is short:

```
Last /@ Sort[{Characters@#, #} & /@ names]
```

{"~/Hex_6.dat", "~/Hex_12.dat", "~/Hex_24.dat", "~/Hex_48.dat", "~/Hex_96.dat", "~/Hex_192.dat"}

Alternatively:

```
Last /@ Sort[{ToExpression[StringJoin[Select[Characters@#, DigitQ]]], #} & /@ names]
```

Comment: +1 this is really nice, although I'm not clear on why this works. Why does `Sort` yield the correct result when used upon a list of characters? My though was that MMA treating a string like a character list was the reason for the unnatural sorting in the first place.

Comment: @Maxwell The reason it works is somewhat subtle :   the lists with smaller numbers just happen to be shorter, so that 
Mathematica canonical ordering is fully suitable for this case, since smaller lists are moved to the left, and for equal-size lists, lexicographical ordering is used. So this code elegantly uses this peculiarity.

Comment: A more concise and faster version of your method would be `names[[Ordering[Characters[names]]]]`

Comment: As @R.M pointed out: The first solution fails if some files are named `~/Hex_012.dat`. (So if some have leading zeroes and some do not.)

Answer (score 9):

You anyway need to parse your list of file names in some way. Here is how I would do it:

```
Clear[sortByIndex];
sortByIndex[names : {__String}, pattern_] :=
    With[{inds = StringCases[names, pattern]},
        names[[Ordering[inds]]] /; FreeQ[inds, {}]
    ];
sortByIndex[__] := $Failed;
```

Since I extract indices all at once with `StringCases`, this should be considerably faster than if parsing would be a part of the comparison function in `SortBy`. I also included some error-checking.

It combines flexibility and error-checking, and encapsulates the sorting part, allowing the user to provide the parsing pattern. So, if we have the other lists as:

```
names1 = {"A_1_1.dat", "A_1_2.dat", "A_1_20.dat", "A_2_1.dat", "A_2_2.dat",  
          "A_2_20.dat"}
```

and

```
names2 = {"T_0.23_run_1.dat", "T_0.23_run_2.dat", "T_0.23_run_20.dat",
   "T_0.24_run_1.dat", "T_0.24_run_2.dat", "T_0.24_run_20.dat"}
```

Then the sorting calls in all 3 cases can look like:

```
sortByIndex[
    names, 
    Shortest[___] ~~ n : DigitCharacter .. ~~ ___ :> ToExpression[n]
]

sortByIndex[
   RandomSample@names1, 
   Shortest[___] ~~ n : DigitCharacter .. ~~ "_" ~~ 
       m : DigitCharacter .. ~~ ___ :> Map[ToExpression, {n, m}]
]
```

and

```
sortByIndex[
    RandomSample@names2, 
    Shortest[___] ~~ n : NumberString ~~ "_run_" ~~ 
       m : DigitCharacter .. ~~ ___ :> Map[ToExpression, {n, m}]
]
```

Note how we can control how specific our patterns should be (I could have used `__` in place of `"_run_"` in the latter case for example), to provide a tighter error-checking, if we need it.

Answer (score 7):

A neat solution, in the same spirit as Chris' answer, would be to sort by the `StringLength`. This implicitly assumes that your file names do not have leading zeros (i.e. `"Hex_00006.dat"`, for example). If this can be guaranteed, then smaller numbers will lead to shorter strings and the default tie breaking for strings of similar length is in the sense of `OrderedQ`, thus giving you the desired sorted list:

```
SortBy[names, StringLength]
(* {"~/Hex_6.dat", "~/Hex_12.dat", "~/Hex_24.dat", "~/Hex_48.dat", 
    "~/Hex_96.dat", "~/Hex_192.dat"} *)
```

Comment: While both Chris's and your solutions are concise, I feel a little uneasy with them because they use certain hidden assumptions valid only for a specific situation. This is a matter of taste, of course - in any case, I like both enough to upvote, +1.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Well, at least my assumptions are explicit and not hidden :)

Comment: My comment is not about the way you or Chris formulated your answer. In a way, it is a meta-comment and describes my personal views. If it reflects anything, it is probably  my own shift from stressing the (and being mostly impressed with) very concise code to see that the code can service more cases than a given case at hand, or at least is structured so that it "self-describes" its own generality / applicability to similar problems and suggests a way to be extended. As I said, this is a matter of taste, and subjective as such, so you don't have to agree with me.

Comment: I just noticed the edit in question, which only confirms (to me anyway) that my point was worth making.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Oh, not saying that your point wasn't relevant. I was rather thinking out aloud on the fact that I stated "This implicitly assumes..." in the answer, but then I go on to explain what I've assumed. That makes it explicit, so saying it was implicit in the first place was unnecessary. Yet, it's common in scientific writing... Don't bother, just some silly musings :)

Comment: I [see](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/10639/4) that you edited my answer with incorrect output.  I'll have to remember to return the favor, assuming I haven't already done so by accident. :o)