# Windows Explorer Natural Order

Tags: files-and-directories, sorting

Currently there are a list of notebooks in Windows that I am processing in a folder. Ideally I would like the notebooks to be concated in the same order as how they display in Windows Explorer.

I found the question [Sort Strings By Natural Order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/sort-strings-by-natural-ordering), but none of the answers seem to use the same technique as Windows Explorer.  After reading [What is the first character in the sort order used by Windows Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290541/what-is-the-first-character-in-the-sort-order-used-by-windows-explorer), it appears that Windows has an internal function that could be used to naturally sort the filenames. I plan to run this only on Windows, so it is okay if it depends on OS-specific functions, though a pure Mathematica way would be nice.

I believe that Windows sorts the files based on [ASCII order](http://www.asciitable.com/) unless a number is encountered.  Ideally I am looking for a function that sorts a list of names into the following order when run. None of the answers linked above correctly order the names below.

```
{"Ie4 01", "Ie4!01", "Ie4_01", "Ie4_128", "Ie5", "Ie6", "Ie401sp2", 
 "Ie501sp2"}
```

```
Ie4 01
Ie4!01
Ie4_01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2
```

Comment: Could you perhaps specify the kind of ordering you are after to make the question self-contained?

Comment: (1) Please include some example strings/names where the Windows ordering does not match the ordering given by methods in the linked Q&A.  (2) How robust does this need to be?  Since you don't want to use the Windows sorting itself you are asking for a reimplementation of that sort ordering, and unless the exact specification is available it will be hard to confirm that it is entirely uniform.

Comment: @YvesKlett I have added an example which I believe demonstrates all the necessary issue encountered with the linked Q&As.

Comment: You can call the DLL function that does the sorting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I Added an example which I believe demonstrates the issue that are encountered with the linked Q&As. I striked through the restraint of using Windows sorting because I'm not particularly concerned about running the script on Linux or OSX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call the windows function that does the sorting directly. The function is [StrCmpLogicalW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947%28VS.85%29.aspx). Note that this is not a cross-platform solution:)

Here is a short example:

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
naturalOrder = 
  DefineDLLFunction["StrCmpLogicalW", "Shlwapi.dll", 
   "int", {"string", "string"}, MarshalStringsAs -> "Unicode"];

strings = {"Ie501sp2", "Ie4!01", "Ie4 01", "Ie4_01", 
   "Ie4_128", "Ie5", "Ie6", "Ie401sp2"};
Sort[strings, naturalOrder[#1, #2] == -1 &] //Column

(*
Ie4 01
Ie4!01
Ie4_01
Ie4_128
Ie5
Ie6
Ie401sp2
Ie501sp2
*)
```

Comment: Great except it doesn't seem to match Windows Explorer. :)  I have no idea why just yet.

Comment: The hat becomes you (^_-)

Comment: I just tried all `StrCmp` on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759952(v=vs.85).aspx) page.  `Map[(
   naturalOrder = 
    DefineDLLFunction[#, "Shlwapi.dll", "int", {"string", "string"}];
   strings = FileNames[];
   Sort[strings, naturalOrder[#1, #2] == 1 &]) &,
 {"StrCmpW",
  "StrCmpCW",
  "StrCmpIW",
  "StrCmpICW",
  "StrCmpLogicalW",
  "StrCmpNW",
  "StrCmpNCW",
  "StrCmpNIW",
  "StrCmpNICW"}
 ]`  Non of them seem to match.

Comment: @LiamWilliam Sorry, forgot the `MarshalStringsAs` option.

Comment: @YvesKlett Hehe, thanks. It does look kind of regal, doesn't it:)

Comment: It sure doth, sirrah!