# Can't sort my list numerically for larger numbers than 10 e.g. 1,10,100,2

Tags: numerics, sorting

I want my files names in real numerical order so 1,2,3,10,12. However it is currently putting them in order like so: 1,10,12,2,3

**Input:**

```
files = FileNames["*"]

SortBy [files, N]
```

**Output:**

```
{"10", "1007680", "1007690", "1007700", "1007710", "1007720", \
"1007730", "1007740", "1032540", "1032550", "1032560", "1032570", \
"1032580", "1032590", "1032600", "1032610", "11250", "11260", \
"11280", "11300", "134110", "134120", "134130", "134140", "134150", \
"20", "30", "301720", "301730", "301740", "301750", "301760", \
"38560", "38570", "38580", "38590", "38600", "40", "50", "60", \
"662830", "662840", "662850", "662860", "662870", "662880"}
```

There must be a simple way to do this that i have missed!

My main goal is that I want *mathematica* to do a set of operations on each file and plot the results in order of the file name. E.g. so that I can see a change from file 1 to file 1000000.

So my thinking is that I want the list to be like this:

```
{"10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "3200", "5600", "10000" ...}
```

Then *Mathematica* will process and plot the files in the correct order.

Comment: That worked thank you! Why is it that SortBy could not do this? I'm still fairly new at this. However mathematica does not appear to be plotting the operations i do on my files in the correct order

Comment: `SortBy[a, ToExpression]` would do it.

Comment: The styling of your question can be improved. Please take the time to read [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [764](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10619/764) and also see [3248](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10619/764).

Comment: Yep that is fantastic, Thank you! It didn't click that i was working with strings, my brain saw numbers and thought integers. I have realised i need to implement this ordering into my actual function to correctly import data from the files into a table in the order of the file name, how would i implement that into this: alldata = Table[Import[files[[i]], "TSV"], {i, 1, L}]      (Where L is the length of the list files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {"10", "1007680", "1007690", "1007700", "1007710", "1007720",
   "1007730", "1007740", "1032540", "1032550", "1032560",
   "1032570", "1032580", "1032590", "1032600", "1032610",
   "11250", "11260", "11280", "11300", "134110", "134120",
   "134130", "134140", "134150", "20", "30", "301720", "301730",
   "301740", "301750", "301760", "38560", "38570", "38580",
   "38590", "38600", "40", "50", "60", "662830", "662840",
   "662850", "662860", "662870", "662880"};

ToString /@ Sort[ToExpression[a]]
```

or

```
SortBy[a, ToExpression]
```

*Edit further to comment.*

```
SetDirectory["Documents"];
filelist = FileNames[];
files = SortBy[filelist, ToExpression];
alldata = Map[Import[#, "TSV"] &, files];
```

Comment: Thank you! I have realised i need to import the files in this order and i'm not sure how to do that my function is:    alldata = Table[Import[files[[i]], "TSV"], {i, 1, L}]   and this is importing them in the original order which is not what i want

Comment: @David I have added something that might work.

Comment: Thank you, it did work however i think it has cause my other operations to not work. What i think i will do is post a new question with all my code and a  better explanation