# How can I sort {S1, S15, S19, S2, ...}?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, sorting

How can I sort this in order from small to large?
Simple `Sort` doesn't work here.

```
list={S1, S15, S19, S2, S26, S37, S50, S4, S8};
(*expectedOut={S1, S2, S4, S8, S15, S19, S26, S37, S50}*)
```

Comment: Related: [sort-strings-by-natural-ordering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/sort-strings-by-natural-ordering)

Answer (score 10):

```
SortBy[list, ToExpression[StringDrop[ToString[#], 1]] &]
```

`Sort` also work but needs longer code compared to previous one:

```
Sort[list, 
 ToExpression[StringDrop[ToString[#1], 1]] < 
   ToExpression[StringDrop[ToString[#2], 1]] &]
```

On the other hand if you used `S[1]` instead of `S1`... then simple `Sort` would be sufficient:

```
list = {S[1], S[15], S[19], S[2], S[26], S[37], S[50], S[4], S[8]};
Sort[list]

(* {S[1], S[2], S[4], S[8], S[15], S[19], S[26], S[37], S[50]} *)
```

Or if you used a more systematic names like `S01` instead of `S1`... then also simple `Sort` would be sufficient:

```
list = {S01, S15, S19, S02, S26, S37, S50, S04, S08};
Sort[list]

(* {S01, S02, S04, S08, S15, S19, S26, S37, S50} *)
```

Comment: Also, indexed variables can be readily formatted in any desired format. For example, either `Format[S[n_]] := "S" <> ToString[n]` or `Format[S[n_]] := Subscript[S, n]`

Comment: Numbers with filling zeros is nice too. Why does `Sort` work with `S[1]`, `S[2]`, etc?

Comment: Could also do `SortBy[list, Characters@*ToString]`

Comment: @Chuy. Very nice. Perhaps you would consider posting as an answer?  Users landing on this page looking for info may well be interested (and usually do not browse comments?).  Also, `list[[OrderingBy[list, Characters@*ToString]]]`

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {S1, S15, S19, S2, S26, S37, S50, S4, S8};

ord = Ordering@(FromDigits@*ToExpression@*Rest@*Characters@*ToString /@
     list)
list[[ord]]
```

> {S1, S2, S4, S8, S15, S19, S26, S37, S50}

---

For the case of leading zeros, the same solution applies:

```
list = {S1, S15, S19, S2, S26, S037, S50, S04, S008};

ord = Ordering@(FromDigits@*ToExpression@*Rest@*Characters@*ToString /@
     list)

list[[ord]]
```

> {S1, S2, S04, S008, S15, S19, S26, S037, S50}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {S100, S1, S15, S19, S2, S26, S37, S50, S4, S8};

Map[ToExpression @* StringJoin] @
 SortBy[Length] @
  Map[Characters @* ToString] @ list
```

> {S1, S2, S4, S8, S15, S19, S26, S37, S50, S100}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {S100, S1, S15, S19, S2, S26, S37, S50, S4, S8};
```

---

A variant using `SortBy`:

```
ToExpression@*StringJoin @@@ 
Sort[Characters@*ToString /@ list /. v_ :> SplitBy[v, LetterQ]]
```

> `{S1, S2, S4, S8, S15, S19, S26, S37, S50, S100}`

Also:

```
f = Symbol@*StringJoin @@@ Thread[{#[[All, 1]], Sort@#[[All, 2 ;;]]}] &;

f[Characters@*ToString /@ list]
```

> `{S1, S2, S4, S8, S15, S19, S26, S37, S50, S100}`

Answer (score 1):

```
num = ToExpression /@ 
  Flatten[StringCases[ToString /@ list, 
    "S" ~~ (x : DigitCharacter ..) -> x]]
list[[Ordering[num]]]
```

yields: {S1, S2, S4, S8, S15, S19, S26, S37, S50}